# Simple algebra simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have

$ \frac{-8rS^{2} \pm \sqrt{64r^{2}S^{4} + 4}}{2}$

Which simplified to

$ -4rS^{2} \pm \sqrt{16r^{2}S^{4} +1}$

But I can’t seem to get this

Comment: $$\pm \frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: hint: $\frac{\sqrt{64}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{64}}{\sqrt{4}} = \sqrt{\frac{64}{4}} \dots $

Comment: I don’t get it, can you help from here

Comment: I don't see what I am doing wrong, $ \frac{\sqrt{64 r^{2}S^{4}+4}}{2}$ = $ \frac{\sqrt{64}\sqrt{r^2S^4}}{2}$ +  \frac{\sqrt{4}}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$D = \frac{-8rS^{2} \pm \sqrt{64r^{2}S^{4} + 4}}{2}$$

Now
\begin{align}
D &= \frac{-8rS^{2} \pm \sqrt{64r^{2}S^{4} + 4}}{2}\\
&=\frac{-8rS^{2}}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{64r^{2}S^{4} + 4}}{2} \\
&= -4rS^2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{64r^{2}S^{4} + 4}}{\sqrt{4}} \\
&= -4rS^2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{64r^{2}S^{4} + 4}{4}}\\
&=-4rS^2 \pm \sqrt{16r^{2}S^{4} + 1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, but can you also explain why its not acceptable to just do this $ \frac{\sqrt{64} \sqrt{r^{2}S^{4}}{2} $  + $ \frac{\sqrt{4}}{2}$  =? $ 4\sqrt{r^2}{S^{4} + 1 $

Comment: @italy you cannot split a square root like this. If you could, you'd get some very weird results - for example $$\sqrt 2=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt1+\sqrt1=1+1=2$$When you spread an operator over a sum like this, it is called [the distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). It _does not_ hold for the square root operator.

Comment: @italy John Doe's comment above this is the reason why. Do you see now?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
64r^2S^4+4=4(16r^2S^4+1)
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{64r^2S^4+4}=\sqrt{4(16r^2S^4+1)}=2\sqrt{16r^2S^4+1}
$$
Finally,
\begin{align}
\frac{-8rS^2\pm\sqrt{64r^2S^4+4}}{2}
&=\frac{-8rS^2\pm2\sqrt{16r^2S^4+1}}{2}\\[6px]
&=\frac{2(-4rS^2\pm\sqrt{16r^2S^4+1}\,)}{2}\\[6px]
&=-4rS^2\pm\sqrt{16r^2S^4+1}
\end{align}

---

Your original equation apparently was
$$
x^2+8rS^2x-1=0
$$
Whenever you have a factor $2$ that can be extracted from the coefficient of the degree $1$ term, the simplification above can be performed: if the equation is $ax^2+2\beta x+c=0$, the quadratic formula yields
\begin{align}
\frac{-2\beta\pm\sqrt{4\beta^2-4ac}}{2a}
&=\frac{-2\beta\pm\sqrt{4(\beta^2-ac)}\,}{2a}\\[6px]
&=\frac{-2\beta\pm2\sqrt{\beta^2-ac}}{2a}\\[6px]
&=\frac{-\beta\pm\sqrt{\beta^2-ac}}{a}
\end{align}
In your case $a=1$, $\beta=-4rS^2$ and $c=-1$.

It's not necessary to remember one more formula, just to recall that the simplification can be done.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{-8rS^2}{2}=-4rS^2$ and $\frac{\sqrt{4X}}{2}=\sqrt{X}$.

Comment: This answer could be helped by doing that last simplification over an extra step ($2=\sqrt 4$ for example). That seems to be where OP's confusion lies.

Comment: @JohnDoe: seeing his comment, the OP believes in the distributivity of the square root over addition !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ohh right I see, well thats a completely different issue!